# Compute $c$ such that $f(x,y)= \frac{c}{1+x^2+x^2y^2+y^2}$ is a probability density function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> The density function of some random vector $(X,Y)$ is:
>   $f(x,y)= \frac{c}{1+x^2+x^2y^2+y^2}$
>   Compute the constant $c$.

We know we can compute the constant from the identity

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)dxdy=1$$

How do I compute this definite  integral when it is defined everywhere except $1+x^2+x^2y^2+y^2 \neq 0$?

Comment: Hint: $$f(x,y)= c\frac1{1+x^2}\frac1{1+y^2}$$

Comment: Thank you. Now I see it :)

Comment: It is thus the "tensor" product of two Cauchy distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dx dy= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}c\frac1{1+x^2}\frac1{1+y^2}dx dy$$
$$1=c\tan^{-1}x \bigg|^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy$$
$$c=\frac{1}{\pi^2}$$